# php mail script to sync gmail into my application

Tags: php, email, email-client

I can write php script to send mail to all  other service provider can we write any php script which can sync my gmail inbox to my web page?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail allows POP-connections, so you should be able to use the imap-functions in php to retrieve you mail.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php
Take a look at the pop3 example by Wil Barath, and you should be good to go.

You will also need to pop-enable your gmail account:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13273